# How will Editor, Strunk & White and Copy Editor be affected by the new <2k edit mechanism?

Tags: support, badges, edits, suggested-edits

How will Editor, Strunk & White and Copy Editor be affected by the new <2k edit mechanism? Will submitting an edit as a <2k user count towards those badges? Will approving someone else's edits count? Will they be entirely unaffected, perhaps because <2k editing will count towards a separate, parallel set of badges?

Comment: Well, I've just submitted an edit on a site that I don't have Editor on, so ideally it'll get approved and we'll see if Editor is earned from it. It makes sense that it would, though.

Comment: Well, I've gotten the Editor badge *elsewhere* by now, so the badge awarding script has run on at least that respect. So you won't get Editor just for submitting an unapproved edit.

Comment: After an edit I suggested included adding two tags, I received the `organizer` badge once the edit was approved.

Comment: Well, [here you go](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/badges/3/editor?userid=1036). Editor for a suggested edit. Now all I have to do is find 99 more options and we can deterministically find out if S&W is awarded. But given this, I'm inclined to believe it will be.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From a post's history perspective (and hence badges) edit suggestions are identical to performing actual edits.

So if you perform a ton of suggested edits you may qualify for the `Strunk & White` badge prior to having full edit rights.

Comment: i have <2k and i made some edits (http://stackoverflow.com/users/461989/igor-milla?tab=reputation you can see all those +2 rep), but according to all kinds of queries (like this http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1024) i have only 1 edit. So is this a bug somewhere or i misunderstand something?

Comment: I got S&W on SO over a month ago (and I had <1k rep back then).

Answer (score 7):

I approved an edit earlier and the person who submitted the edit was listed as the last editor on the post, not me.  I think that's as it should be.  Since they're doing the work and getting credit for the edit, the edit should count for editor badges as well.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why suggested edits shouldn't count. They're edits just like all others. If you manage to get 100 edits through the suggestion system, you surely deserve a reward!

I can see approving edits count towards its own badge, maybe ("Supervisor"?), but nothing more than a bronze one to be honest.

Comment: I can also see Community getting reps! ...and badges! _...gold_ badges!

Comment: Community _deserves_ a gold badge or two, for all the junk it has to put up with.

Comment: @Pop It does have a diamond.