# Do suggested edits count towards strunk and white badge?

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How will Editor, Strunk & White and Copy Editor be affected by the new <2k edit mechanism?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76916/how-will-editor-strunk-white-and-copy-editor-be-affected-by-the-new-2k-edit-m)

As it says in the title really - I couldn't find any mention of whether approved suggested edits count towards the strunk and white badge, or you have to wait until your reputation is at 2k?

Also, do edits to your own posts count towards the badge or is it just others?

Comment: I know that edits on your own posts don't count towards the badge.

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76916/150235).