# Tag Editor badge under the new edit approval system

Tags: support, badges, suggested-edits

Under the new edit approval system, if a user who normally can't edit a Tag Wiki proposes an edit will they earn the Tag Editor badge if their edit is approved?

Comment: I'm 90% sure the answer is 'yes'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from [how things were explained by waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76916/how-will-editor-strunk-white-and-copy-editor-be-affected-by-the-new-2k-edit-m/77857#77857) with regards to all the other editing badges, you'll have for all intents and purposes contributed a tag wiki edit, which is sufficient to earn the badge.

Comment: confirmed @Grace