# Should I have gotten "Tag Editor"?

Tags: support, tags, badges, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag Editor badge under the new edit approval system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78425/tag-editor-badge-under-the-new-edit-approval-system)

I recently [edited the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4254876/2) for the [jquery-validate](/questions/tagged/jquery-validate) tag. My edit had to go through the approval process. The edit was approved but I haven't received the "Tag Editor" badge.

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78425/153691) question and answer, I should have gotten the badge. Am I just being impatient?

Comment: Short answer: most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just received the badge. Sorry for being impatient!

Comment: I think they just fixed it yesterday as I also got mine today.

Comment: @Yet Another Geek: Interesting... Thanks `:)`

Comment: It sometimes just takes a while...